# How to know if EGOImageView finished loading image from a URL?

Tags: ios, egoimageview

I'm using EGOImageView and wish hide the view until it did finished loading the image from a url. Is there a method can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method `imageViewLoadedImage:` will be called when the image is loaded.

Check [EGOImageViewDelegate](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/blob/master/EGOImageView/EGOImageView.h#L48).

Comment: should I call this method or it can execute automatically after the image loaded?